# Extended slice that goes to beginning of sequence with negative stride

Tags: python, list, slice

Bear with me while I explain my question.  Skip down to the bold heading if you already understand extended slice list indexing.

In python, you can index lists using slice notation. Here's an example:

```
>>> A = list(range(10))
>>> A[0:5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You can also include a stride, which acts like a "step":

```
>>> A[0:5:2]
[0, 2, 4]
```

The stride is also allowed to be negative, meaning the elements are retrieved in reverse order:

```
>>> A[5:0:-1]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

But wait!  I wanted to see `[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]`.  Oh, I see, I need to decrement the start and end indices:

```
>>> A[4:-1:-1]
[]
```

What happened?  It's interpreting -1 as  being at the end of the array, not the beginning.  I know you can achieve this as follows:

```
>>> A[4::-1]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

But you can't use this in all cases.  For example, in a method that's been passed indices.

### My question is:

Is there any good pythonic way of using extended slices with negative strides *and explicit start and end indices* that include the first element of a sequence?

This is what I've come up with so far, but it seems unsatisfying.

```
>>> A[0:5][::-1]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think this is probably as good as I will get it.  Thanks to Abgan for sparking the idea.  This relies on the fact that None in a slice is treated as if it were a missing parameter.  Anyone got anything better?

```
def getReversedList(aList, end, start, step):
    return aList[end:start if start!=-1 else None:step]
```

*edit: check for `start==-1`, not `0`*

This is still not ideal, because you're clobbering the usual behavior of -1.  It seems the problem here is two overlapping definitions of what's supposed to happen.  Whoever wins takes away otherwise valid invocations looking for the other intention.

Comment: You could replace `None` by `-len(a) + start`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399067/extended-slice-that-goes-to-beginning-of-sequence-with-negative-stride#400118

Comment: To be clear, J.F. Sebastian has the best solution.  Completely eliminate the conditional and *always* use negative indexing, as in aList[end:start-len(aList):negativeStep].  No special checks for extended slices with a negative step.

Answer (score 5):

It is error-prone to change the semantics of `start` and `stop`. Use `None` or `-(len(a) + 1)` instead of `0` or `-1`. The semantics is not arbitrary. See  Edsger W. Dijkstra's article ["Why numbering should start at zero"](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html).

```
>>> a = range(10)
>>> start, stop, step = 4, None, -1
```

Or

```
>>> start, stop, step = 4, -(len(a) + 1), -1
>>> a[start:stop:step]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Or

```
>>> s = slice(start, stop, step)
>>> a[s]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

[When `s` is a sequence the negative indexes in `s[i:j:k]` are treated specially](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

> If `i` or `j` is negative, the index is relative to the end of the string:
>   `len(s) + i` or `len(s) + j` is substituted. But note that `-0` is still `0`.

that is why `len(range(10)[4:-1:-1]) == 0` because it is equivalent to `range(10)[4:9:-1]`.

Comment: So what is happening with start and stop with the negative stride? Is the semantics of start and end changed (especially with the negative ones?) I don't get it.

Comment: @huggie: if `step < 0` then `start` should be *larger* then `stop` or the result is empty.

Answer (score 2):

```
[ A[b] for b in range(end,start,stride) ]
```

Slower, however you can use negative indices, so this should work:

```
[ A[b] for b in range(9, -1, -1) ]
```

I realize this isn't using slices, but thought I'd offer the solution anyway if using slices specifically for getting the result isn't a priority.

Comment: The problem though is that it would not work with strings. You would need to create separate code for each sequence type (string, list, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following doesn't satisfy you:

```
def getReversedList(aList, end, start, step):
    if step < 0 and start == 0:
         return aList[end::step]
    return aList[end:start:step]
```

or does it? :-)

Comment: I had considered that, requiring two separate cases seems like it should be unnecessary.  But you've given me an idea...

Answer (score 1):

> [But](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399067/extended-slice-that-goes-to-beginning-of-sequence-with-negative-stride#399082) you can't use that if you are
>   storing your indices in variables for
>   example.

Is this satisfactory?

```
>>> a = range(10)
>>> start = 0
>>> end = 4
>>> a[4:start-1 if start > 0 else None:-1]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say very few people fully understand everything that you can do with extended slicing, so unless you really need the extra performance I'd do it the "obvious" way:

`rev_subset = reversed(data[start:stop])`

Comment: Not only few people understand the slices, but also the extended slices are f***ed up due to the "minus means count from the end" convention. I'd never use extended slices.

Answer (score 0):

```
a[4::-1]
```

Example:

```
Python 2.6 (r26:66714, Dec  4 2008, 11:34:15) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5488)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = list(range(10))
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a[4:0:-1]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> a[4::-1]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>>
```

The reason is that the second term is interpreted as "while not index ==".  Leaving it out is "while index in range".

Comment: I mentioned that in the question.  But you can't use that if you are storing your indices in variables for example.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in case someone like me is looking for answers:

```
>>> A[5-1::-1]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

>>> A[4:1:-1]
[4, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `slice(start, stop, step)` object, which is such that

```
s=slice(start, stop, step)
print a[s]
```

is the same as

```
print a[start : stop : step]
```

and, moreover, you can set any of the arguments to `None` to indicate nothing in between the colons. So in the case you give, you can use `slice(4, None, -1)`.