# Understanding string reversal via slicing

Tags: python, string, slice

I was looking for a way to print a string backwards, and after a quick search on google, I found this method:

Suppose `a` is a string variable. This will return the `a` string backwards:

```
a[::-1]
```

Can anyone explain how that works?

Comment: **Please seealso**: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33457266/42223 which addresses this feature of python that some may find "quirky".

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Sure, the `[::]` is the [extended slice](https://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices) operator.  It allows you to take substrings.  Basically, it works by specifying which elements you want as [begin:end:step], and it works for all sequences.  Two neat things about it:

- You can omit one or more of the elements and it does "the right thing"
- Negative numbers for begin, end, and step have meaning

For begin and end, if you give a negative number, it means to count from the end of the sequence.  For instance, if I have a list:

```
l = [1,2,3]
```

Then `l[-1]` is 3, `l[-2]` is 2, and `l[-3]` is 1.

For the `step` argument, a negative number means to work *backwards* through the sequence.  So for a list::

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

You could write `l[::-1]` which basically means to use a step size of -1 while reading through the list.  Python will "do the right thing" when filling in the start and stop so it iterates through the list backwards and gives you `[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]`.

I've given the examples with lists, but strings are just another sequence and work the same way.  So `a[::-1]` means to build a string by joining the characters you get by walking backwards through the string.

Comment: "The right thing" can be a bit confusing when using a negative step/stride.  [Example here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/399067/936083).

Answer (score 8):

The "-1" part represents the "step" part of the slicing—in this case, it goes through the string 1 character at a time, but backwards (a negative step means start from the end of the string). If you specify the step to be 2, for instance, you would get every other character of the string, starting with the first one. If you specify a step of -2, then you'd get every other character of the string, starting with the last character and working backwards.

So, in a nutshell, if `a = '12345'`:

- `a[::2]` becomes `135`
- `a[::-1]` becomes `54321`
- `a[::-2]` becomes `531`

Answer (score 6):

I think the following makes a bit more sense for print strings in reverse, but maybe that's just me:

```
for char in reversed( myString ):  
  print( char, end = "" )
```

Comment: It's the python 3 way of not newlining at the end of each print.

In python 2.x, you could just write
print( char, )

Comment: Of course, this prints out the string; it does not create a new string that is the old string reversed (''.join(reversed(myString)) will do that, however).

Comment: Indeed. However, the OP only asked for "printing." Hence a "printing" solution.

Comment: you could allways do: ''.join(reversed(myString0)) to get the string.

Answer (score 3):

It's the [extended slice notation](https://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices):

```
sequence[start:end:step]
```

In this case, step -1 means backwards, and omitting the start and end means you want the whole string.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

```
variable = "string"
message = ""
for b in variable:
    message = b+message
print (message)
```

and it prints: gnirts

Answer (score 2):

It's called Slice Notation in Python and you can read a bit more of how it works here:

[Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

Answer (score 2):

It's using extended slicing - a string is a sequence in Python, and shares some methods with other sequences (namely lists and tuples). There are three parts to slicing - start, stop and step. All of them have default values - start defaults to 0, stop defaults to len(sequence), and step defaults to 1. By specifying [::-1] you're saying "all the elements in sequence a, starting from the beginning, to the end going backward one at a time.

This feature was introduced in Python 2.3.5, and you can read more in the [What's New docs](http://www.python.org/doc/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html).

Answer (score 2):

[::-1] gives a slice of the string a. the full syntax is `a[begin:end:step]`
which gives a[begin], a[begin+step], ... a[end-1]. WHen step is negative, you start at end and move to begin.

Finally, begin defaults to the beginning of the sequence, end to the end, and step to -1.

Answer (score 1):

a string is essentially a sequence of characters and so the slicing operation works on it.  What you are doing is in fact:

-> get an slice of 'a' from start to end in steps of 1 backward.

Answer (score 1):

It's basic step notation, consider the functionality of:

a[2:4:2]

What happens is the index is sliced between position 2 and 4, what the third variable does is it sets the step size starting from the first value. In this case it would return a[2], since a[4] is an upper bounds only two values are return and no second step takes place. The (-) minus operator simply reverses the step output.

Answer (score 1):

Using extended slice syntax

```
word = input ("Type a word which you want to reverse: ")
def reverse(word):
  word = word[::-1]
  return word
print (reverse(word))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the list below

```
l=[12,23,345,456,67,7,945,467]
```

Another trick for reversing a list may be :

```
l[len(l):-len(l)-1:-1] [467, 945, 7, 67, 456, 345, 23, 12]

l[:-len(l)-1:-1] [467, 945, 7, 67, 456, 345, 23, 12]

l[len(l)::-1] [467, 945, 7, 67, 456, 345, 23, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reversed() function. 
For example

```
x = "abcd"
for i in reversed(x):
        print(i, end="")
print("\n")
L = [1,2,3]
for i in reversed(L):
        print(i, end="")
```

prints `dcba` and `321`

Answer (score 0):

the first two bounds default to 0 and the length of the sequence, as before, and a stride of −1 indicates that the slice should go from right to left instead of the usual left to right. The effect, therefore, is to reverse the sequence.

```
name="ravi"
print(name[::-1]) #ivar
```

Answer (score -1):

we can use append and pop to do it

```
def rev(s):
    i = list(s)
    o = list()
    while len(i) > 0:
        o.append(t.pop())

    return ''.join(o)
```

Comment: Why would you suggest an alternative method for reversing a string when the OP clearly wanted to know why `a[::-1]` works?

Comment: This is not the relevant answer, please read the question again.

Answer (score -1):

Without using reversed or [::-1], here is a simple version based on recursion i would consider to be the most readable:

```
def reverse(s):

  if len(s)==2:
    return s[-1] + s[0]

  if len(s)==1:
    return s[0]

  return s[-1] + reverse(s[1:len(s)-1]) + s[0]
```