# slicing strings in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766141/reverse-a-string-in-python)

I tried searching the python documentation for a certain slicing exapmle
lets say I have this string

```
a = "ABCD"
```

when I write:

```
a[::-1]
```

I get the reversed string

```
"DCBA"
```

I can't understand how exectaly it works. None of the examples I saw were with two colons. what does it mean? how does it work?

thank you!

Comment: um... why would you downvote this?  Vote to close as duplicate - yes, but why be rude to a new user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full syntax of a slicing is

```
a[start:stop:step]
```

The `step` value denotes by how much to increase the index when going from one element of the slice to the next one.  A value of `-1` consequently means "go backwards".  If `start` and `stop` are omitted as in your example, the default is to use the whole string (or more generally, the whole sequence, as this also works for lists and tuples).