# Why does this "[::-1]" return a reversed list in Python?

Tags: python, list, reverse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good Primer for Python Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)
>   [reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766141/reverse-a-string-in-python)

I've seen this syntax crop up in a few code snippets I've seen lately, and I'm curious as to what it does. If I have `my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]`, and I execute `my_list[::-1]`, I'm given a list with the elements reversed `[5,4,3,2,1]`. Could someone please explain to me what this actually does, and show the difference between `[:]` notation and `[::]`? Or at least refer me to a resource that does.

I'm sure if I had a good Python book it would be in there, but I don't. And it's impossible to search Google for something like this since the `[::]` gets ignored. Thanks!

Comment: there are a lot of posts on this .. I once asked about the same and was told to search .. and found a bunch that explain it.

Comment: [This one for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766141/reverse-a-string-in-python?lq=1)

Comment: Incidentally, [SymbolHound makes searching for punctuation easy](http://symbolhound.com/?q=python+[%3A%3A]). Google rules at many things but programming is their weakest area by far...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is no difference between `[:]` and `[::]`.

But `[::-1]` does something else: it has a negative step parameter. The absence of the start and stop parameters means the complete array. The negative step parameter means that data is taken in reverse order, from the end to the start.