# Read words backwards using python

Tags: python

I want to make a program that reads a text file from my directory and prints out the words backwards.

for example:
My text file contains this sentance: "Others follow the British historian A. J. P. Taylor"

using this code:

```
f=open('c:/Python27/ww2.txt','r')
print f.readline()
```

it will print this: "Others follow the British historian A. J. P. Taylor"

What I want to print is this: "rolyaT .P.J.A niarotsih hsitirB eht wollof srethO"

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Gee, if only there was a way to have `sorted` lists and then `reverse` them in Python....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read a file in reverse order using python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301789/read-a-file-in-reverse-order-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question, just use reverse string indexing. it should look like this:

```
s="Whatever"
print s[::-1]
```

It will then print s backwards

Answer (score 3):

```
print f.readline()[::-1]
```

This is a duplicate of [reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766141/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Comment: So why are you answering it?