# How reverse works in python

Tags: python, reverse

I have an array which contains some elements.

How by doing `arr[::-1]` sort the entire array?

What is the logic behind that?

Comment: `arr[::-1]` does not sort a list, it only reverses a list.

Comment: Sorting the array would change the order of all its elements such that `arr[i] <= arr[i+1]`. `arr[::-1]` doesn't do that, it just reverses the order in which they occur in the array.

Answer (score 5):

This is [extended slice](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices) syntax. It works by doing [begin:end:step] - by leaving begin and end off and specifying a step of -1, it reverses a string.
Example:

```
>>> 'hello world'[::-1]
'dlrow olleh'
```

**See also**

- [alternate simple approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6238928/42223)
- [alternate simple approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/766291/42223)
- [alternate explanation of slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)