# swap elements of list in recursive call python

Tags: python, recursion, swap

I want to make simple function swap random element in list. 
but it doesn't work in recursive call.

in first recursive call, element swapping work, 
but nested recursive call(or nested recursive call in first recursive call) doesn't work.

I don't know why only swap in first recursive call works.

below are result.

Thank you all.

```
def change(lst):
    if len(lst)>4:
        a, b = np.random.randint(0, len(lst)), np.random.randint(0, len(lst))
        print(lst)
        lst[a], lst[b] = lst[b], lst[a]
        print(lst)
        mid = int(len(lst)/2)
        change(lst[:mid])
        change(lst[mid:])
k = list(range(0, 20))
change(k)
print(k)
```

`

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[0, 19, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 1]
[0, 19, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 19, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 19, 2, 0, 4]
[3, 0, 2, 19, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[5, 6, 8, 7, 9]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 1]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 1]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[10, 14, 12, 13, 11]
[15, 16, 17, 18, 1]
[15, 16, 17, 18, 1]
[0, 19, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 1] <= result.
```

Comment: See [Why are slices in Python 3 still copies and not views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902235/why-are-slices-in-python-3-still-copies-and-not-views)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your recursive calls:

```
change(lst[:mid])
change(lst[mid:])
```

you use a **slicing operator**. The slicing operator constructs a **new list**, so your **changes are made on a new list** and are not reflected on the original list (since it is a *copy*).

What you can do is use indices instead:

```
def change(lst,frm=0,to=None):
    if to is None: # set the default to the end of the list
        to = len(lst)
    if to-frm > 4:
        a, b = np.random.randint(frm,to), np.random.randint(frm,to)
        print(lst)
        lst[a], lst[b] = lst[b], lst[a]
        print(lst)
        mid = (frm+to)//2
        change(lst,frm,mid)
        change(lst,mid,to)
```

Then we obtain:

```
>>> k = list(range(0, 20))
>>> change(k)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 12, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 12, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 12, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 12, 8, 9, 10, 11, 5, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 12, 8, 9, 5, 11, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 12, 8, 9, 5, 11, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 12, 8, 9, 5, 11, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> print(k)
[0, 1, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 12, 8, 9, 5, 11, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Comment: Really, Thank you. I don't know slice operator make a copy of the list.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you create *copies* of the original list by `lst[:mid]`, `lst[mid:]`. A solution is to pass to `change()` the same list and (separately) the range to process.