# Write s[::-1] using explicit indices

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot write `s[::-1]` which reverses the string `s` using explicit indices. I want to write `s[a:b:-1]` but I don't know what to put for `a` and `b`. Here is a code sample, it should produce `fedcba`:

```
s = 'abcdef'
s[::-1]
```

From the documentation:

> Slice indices have useful defaults; an omitted first index defaults to
> **zero**, an omitted second index defaults to the size of the string being
> sliced.

Comment: Please explain how should be the output?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Why "can't" you write `s[::-1]`? You *can* write it and it produces the output you want.

Comment: "I don't know what to put for a and b" - what did you *try* to put and what was the problem with it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I can - I just want to understand how I can write this using explicit indices. It's a valid question - I should be able to write this using `s[a:b:-1]` where a,b are some expressions.

Comment: ...so, it's a curiosity question, not a practical problem? Our rules require that problems be _practical_ -- that their answers change how you go about the practice of programming. (See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297058/when-is-asking-questions-out-of-curiosity-off-topic on [meta])

Comment: `s[len(s):None:-1]` seems to work

Comment: @Charles You could contrive a situation where you dynamically decide values for `a, b, c` to then pass to `s[a:b:c]`…

Comment: @deceze, sure; such a scenario is given (with a specific attempt at a working implementation and a specific failure mode encountered), we have a practical question. f/e, not having a _practical_ failure, we can't say whether `None` is an adequate answer in the `b` field, or if it really needs to be `0` (or another non-negative integer value); because the only basis on which an answer can be determined to be correct is the entirely subjective "does the OP consider their curiosity resolved?".

Comment: Here's another one that hasn't been listed yet: ``s[-1:-len(s)-1:-1]``, though ``s[None:None:-1]`` is probably more readable.

Comment: Would you not then say that the python documentation is wrong? Clearly, omitted indices default to `None`. If one experiments with slicing `s` it is clear the default is `None` if an index is omitted.

Comment: I think this might boil down to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399067/extended-slice-that-goes-to-beginning-of-sequence-with-negative-stride which essentially asks "why does using -1 as `stop` value not work as expected". Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798136/python-reverse-stride-slicing

Comment: @s5s, ...I would say that the Python documentation about default behavior doesn't cover the negative-step case, yes. OTOH, the negative-step case doesn't _happen_ in the presence of purely default behavior. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy But even with non-negative step size, Using `None` in place of omitted indices produces consistent results. For example, `s[None, None]` or `s[None:3]` etc. It appears, it is more correct to suggest that the default is `None` if an index is omitted. I haven't looked at the implementation but I would imagine that it defaults to `None`.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the implementation recognized `None` as a placeholder, and replaced it with something else (such as a non-negative index with a specific numeric value) later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to fill all 3 placeholders you can do

```
s[len(s):None:-1]
```

Edit: as suggested by @deceze, this works too

```
s[None:None:-1]
```

Comment: `None` for the start would do fine too…

Comment: Well, this is what happens when you left it empty, it becomes `None` and Python handles it. So I think this is still not an answer.

Comment: @Asocia If the question is to find values for `a, b, c` that will replicate the behaviour of `s[::-1]` with `s[a:b:c]`, then surely `None` is a valid solution.

Comment: Also, omitted indices default to zero or to the size of the string, at least as stated in the question.

Comment: @deceze Then why @Pani answered `s[len(s):None:-1]` but not `s[None:None:-1]`? They tried to find `a` and `len(s)` was a valid value for `a`, tried to find `b` but couldn't find and put `None`. Revealing the obvious, `None`, shouldn't be considered as answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to write s[a:b:-1] but I don't know what to put for a and b.

There you go:

```
>>> s = 'abcdef'
>>> a =  len(s) - 1 
>>> b = -len(s) - 1 
>>> s[a:b:-1]
'fedcba'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are values for a and b that work:

```
lst = list('abcd')

a = b = None
print (lst[a:b:-1]) # returns ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']

a = len(lst)
b = 0 - len(lst) - 1 # b = -5

print (lst[a:b:-1]) # returns ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

Answer (score -1):

this should do it.

```
s[len(s)::-1]
```

Comment: That's providing an explicit value in the `a` placeholder, but not the `b` one; the OP wants both.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.